If $G$ acts simply transitively on $X$, find functions $f(gx) = gf(x)$
A group $G$ acts simply transitively on a set $X$, if for all $x, x' \in X$, there exists a unique $g \in G$ such that $gx = x'$.
I was asked to find all functions $f : X \rightarrow X$ such that $f(gx) = gf(x)$.
My first guess was that this set of functions are exctly the bijections from $X$ to itself, but this is not true: if $X = G = \mathbb{Z}_4$, $f(1) = 2, f(2) =1$ and $f(x) = x$ otherwise, then $f$ is clearly a bijection, but if we pick $g = 1$ and $x = 2$, we get that $gf(x) = 1 + f(2) = 2$, and $f(gx) = f(1+2) = 3$ (in this example, $G$ acts on itself by addition mod 4).
The converse is true - i.e. if $f$ satisfies the condition than $f$ is a bijection.

Just to enable additonal searching: simply transitive = sharply transitive = regular.

A special case to get some insight. Every group acts simply transitively on itself by left translations. Now take $G=(\mathbb R,+)$; for a fixed $g\in G$, $f(g+x)=g+f(x)$ for all $x\in G$ defines a straight line of slope $1$ and intersection with the y-axes at $y_0=f(g)-g$.

A little curiosity I'll note is that it seems like such function should just be translations, i.e. $x \mapsto gx$ for some $g$, but you can convince yourself that that would only be possible in an Abelian group. I'd be interested to know a word for what these functions do. My answer gives a characterization: $x \mapsto h(x_0, x)y$, but I don't know how to describe such a map. It's like a translation, but what you're translating stays the same and how far you translate varies.

I will show an explicit bijection $A \equiv \{f : X \to X \mid f(gx) = gf(x)\} \leftrightarrow X$.
First, note that $G$ acts simply transitively, so we can define $h : X \times X \to G$ such that $h(x, x')$ is the unique element of $G$ satisfying the equation $h(x,x')x = x'$.
Fix $x_0 \in X$. Define $F : A \to X$ by $F(f) = f(x_0)$, i.e. $F$ is just evaluation at $x_0$.
$F$ is an injection: Observe
$$
f(x) = f(h(x_0, x) x_0) = h(x_0, x) f(x_0)
$$
If $F(f_1) = F(f_2)$, then $f_1(x_0) = f_2(x_0)$, which gives
$$
f_1(x) = h(x_0, x) f_1(x_0) =  h(x_0, x)f_2(x_0) = f_2(x)
$$
That is, $f_1 = f_2$.
F is a surjection: Given $y \in X$, define $f_y : X \to X$ by
$$
f_y(x) = h(x_0, x)y
$$
We have $gh(x_0, x)x_0 = gx$, so by uniqueness $h(x_0, gx) = gh(x_0, x)$. Thus
$$
f_y(gx) = h(x_0, gx)y = gh(x_0, x)y = gf_y(x)
$$
verifying that $f_y \in A$.
Taking $e \in G$ to be the identity, we have $ex_0 = x_0$, so by uniqueness $h(x_0, x_0) = e$. Thus,
$$
f_y(x_0) = h(x_0, x_0)y = ey = y
$$
That is, $F(f_y) = y$.

We see that there is almost a canonical bijection between $\{f : X \to X \mid f(gx) = gf(x)\}$ and $X$. The only choice we had to make was $x_0 \in X$. In other words, all that we need to know about such an $f$ is where it sends one point; the group action tells us everything else.
